# How can I utilize a condition on className to run a function?

Tags: javascript

I am designing a trivia app where 1 of 4 options can be selected. Upon clicking the element, the class changes from `selectedFalse` to `selectedTrue`. Then, the idea is that clicking the "submit" button will pull the next question (working) and increase the `correct` variable (not working)

**PullQuestions()** Iterates through the questions. I've included the code for just one of the questions.

```
if (question.id == 0) {

    document.getElementById("headerQ").innerHTML = question[0].headerQ;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = question[0].content;
    document.getElementById("op1").innerHTML = question[0].op1;
    document.getElementById("op2").innerHTML = question[0].op2;
    document.getElementById("op3").innerHTML = question[0].op3;
    document.getElementById("op4").innerHTML = question[0].op4;

    if (op1.className == "selectedTrue") {
        isCorrect();
    }

    console.log("Scoring System Logging: ", question.id, correct);
    }
}
```

Because the condition is true, I was expecting the `isCorrect()` function to fire. According to the console, the function is not firing.

**isCorrect() Function**

```
function isCorrect() {
    correct++;
    console.log("isCorrect()", "Scoring System Logging: ", question.id,  correct);
}
```

**Submit Button Function**

```
function submitA() {
    question.id++;
    pullQuestions();

    console.log("submitA()", "Scoring System Logging: ", question.id, correct);
}
```

I don't know why I can't get the score to increase based on the className of the selected object.

**EDIT**

Here's the code for the "options." The styles work accordingly. Clicking any of the options sets the class from `selectedFalse` to `selectedTrue`. Clicking any other option will revert the original selection back to false. Additionally, clicking the same option twice will revert back to false. I can confirm this is working both visually (true turns green, false turns orange) and in the Console tab.

```
// Option 1
function select1() {
    
        if (op1.className == "selectionFalse") {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionTrue";
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionFalse";
    
        console.log("selected1()", "If Condition", op1.className);
        }
    
        else {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionFalse";
        console.log("selected1()", "If Condition", op1.className);
        }   
    }
    
// Option 2
        function select2() {
    
        if (op2.className == "selectionFalse") {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionTrue";
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionFalse";
    
        console.log("selected2()", "If Condition", op2.className);
        }
    
        else {
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionFalse";
        console.log("selected1()", "If Condition", op2.className);
        }   
    } 
    
// Option 3
        function select3() {
    
        if (op3.className == "selectionFalse") {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionTrue";
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionFalse";
    
        console.log("selected3()", "If Condition", op3.className);
        }
    
        else {
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionFalse";
        console.log("selected3()", "If Condition", op3.className);
        }   
    }

// Option 4
        function select4() {
    
        if (op4.className == "selectionFalse") {
        document.getElementById("op1").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op2").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op3").className = "selectionFalse";
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionTrue";
    
        console.log("selected4()", "If Condition", op4.className);
        }
    
        else {
        document.getElementById("op4").className = "selectionFalse";
        console.log("selected4()", "If Condition", op4.className);
        }   
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what `op1.className` is set to? It would help to see a full working example of the issue, including the HTML, as I'm sure you can simplify and DRY this code up

Comment: According to what you say, the problem is here " if (op1.className == "selectedTrue") " so we can't help unless we what is op1 and it would be better if you share the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

if you want check if an element has a class name, you should do:

```
if(op1.classlist.contains("selectedTrue")){
 // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a shot and I got an error in the console tab. "Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'contains'. I don't think that's an issue because when the trivia part loads there is no option set to `selectedTrue`. Though, when I click the `op1` button and then click submit the function still doesn't fire.